# How to scrape a map on a website for informations stored in popups?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, maps

I'm relatively new to web scraping so I'm not sure about which approach I should use to collect informations in a specific scenario in which the informations are stored on a map and displayed in popups, such as : https://utils.ocim.fr/cartocim2/

Basically :

1. the website shows a map,
2. contact informations are displayed in popups,
3. a popup will appear when clicking on a geo-tag button,
4. targeted informations are those lines stored in that popup

I was thinking of using `selenium + xpath` method but I'm unsure regarding the way to deal :

1. with this amount of buttons that have to be clicked on
2. with the popups.

Would you have any resources / tips to advise me to know where to start ?

Answer (score 1):

With great difficulty

Here's a start but it gets a little more complicated as the markers start overlapping so clicking the elements fails, might need to add a step to zoom in etc

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import pandas as pd
url_base = r'https://utils.ocim.fr/cartocim2/'



driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\username\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url_base) #open page

#find all the icons
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.leaflet-pane.leaflet-marker-pane > img')



import time

output = [] #temp table to append into
for i in range(5): #chaneg to len(links) when done
    links[i].click() #click on first icon
    output.append(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="popup-header"]')[0].text) #get the text of the name
    time.sleep(1) #sleep
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#initmap').click() #reset the map - needed as without it the next icon might not be on the screen due to map relocation or popup overlap
    time.sleep(1)
```